# How to refer to the name of the xlsm file from inside an addon?

Tags: excel, vba, add-on

In short: I want to access the name of the .xlsm file calling an .xlam add-on, from inside the code of the add-on.

In more detail: I'm using Excel to allow people to export create data files after editing worksheets.
I first created a workbook that saved those data files with the name of the workbook followed by .data. That worked. Now I've turned that workbook as an add-on (.xlam file).
That works also, but the name of the saved data file is the name of the add-on, not the name of the xlsm file containing the xlam file.

Solved - the code now reads as follows:

```
(compute myOutputComputedEarlier as content to save in file)
...
fileAndPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".data"
Open fileAndPath For Output As #1
Print #1, myOutputComputedEarlier
Close #1
```

Comment: I kinda agree. I think if someone wants to down vote a post, they should be forced to give a reason. They might have a perfectly good reason for it but atleast it gives OP a chance to respond

Comment: Did not downvote, but, looking at the edit history:  Including a sample of your code (which would have identified `ThisWorkbook` being used, et cetera) from the start might have been of use, and made sure it didn't look like a "do my work for me" post.  Your question structure is good though - and the summary paragraph at the start is nice and clear - however you need to put2 spaces at the end of a line for a line break, which is why your second paragraph is all bunched up like that.  Not sure why this has a "VTC - Off Topic" either

Comment: @Chronocidal : thank you for your answer.  

Yes I notice I did not mention I was using ThisWorkbook in the question. That's the only context I can see that I could have added.  

I think it's more a "what's the syntax for" question than a "do my work" question.   

   didn't know the 2-spaces thing, it's good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try ActiveWorkbook instead of ThisWorkbook, but its hard to say without any code from you.